# Multiple (Device-specific) storyboards in in iOS 7.0 Swift projects

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7, swift

Has anyone gotten Swift to play nice enough with iOS 7 to handle multiple storyboards?

At the very least, has anyone gotten device suffixes to work properly? Whenever I rename Main.storyboard in the Master-Detail example project to Main~iPad and/or Main~iPhone, I seem to get load errors.

I think it has something to do with device suffixes, because the following will do what I want :

```
    var window: UIWindow?
    var storyboard: UIStoryboard?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
    //device suffixes ~iPad and ~iPhone don't work right now, in fact, a lot of .storyboard stuff is borked
    self.window = UIWindow() //window doesn't have an init with frame class, so we need to set that to the screen bounds in order to have touch
    self.window!.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    //Since I'm targeting iOS 7 and later, we can't use UISplitViewController everywhere (it becomes universal in iOS 8)
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
       self.storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main~iPad", bundle: nil)
       self.window!.rootViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateInitialViewController() as UIViewController
       //iPad-specific initialization
       let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as UISplitViewController
       let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.endIndex-1] as UINavigationController
       splitViewController.delegate = navigationController.topViewController as DetailViewController
    }else{ //iPhone / iPod
       self.storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main~iPhone", bundle: nil)
       self.window!.rootViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateInitialViewController() as UINavigationController
       //iPhones should just have a navigation controller as their root view
    }
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible() //got to manually key since we're initializing our window by hand
    //at this point we have the iPad storyboard or the iPhone storyboard loaded
    return true
}
```

I know that it looks like we're going to be moving away from device-specific tags, but answering this will be important for people that need to keep supporting iOS 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device specific stuff and orientation is changing soon. Swift source compatibility for iOS 7 and Mavericks isn't guaranteed but binary compatibility is. Maybe you're running up against the limits of the compatibility.

Comment: I assumed as much, but this almost feels like an unintentional regression in Xcode 6. No pre-6 Xcode projects with device-specific storyboards will run without something like the hackaround I found. 



I guess that's their call to make, and it is a point release after all, but there's going to be some serious backwards compatibility problems if they're making changes this drastic.